# AfxLoadLibrary vs. LoadLibrary

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, mfc

I have an MFC application that needs to load a DLL dynamically.  The DLL will be used to retrieve a run-time value and then be unloaded.  Do I need to create an MFC DLL and load it via `AfxLoadLibrary()` or can I create a traditional C++ dll and use the Win32 `LoadLibrary()` call?  Does it matter?

Comment: Are you planning on using MFC in the library that you are going to create?

Comment: No.  The DLL is strictly C++ and will not include any of the AFX-based headers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is explicitly mentioned in the Remarks section of the MSDN Library article:

> Be sure to use AfxLoadLibrary and AfxFreeLibrary (instead of the Win32 functions LoadLibrary and FreeLibrary) if your application uses multiple threads and if it dynamically loads an extension DLL. Using AfxLoadLibrary and AfxFreeLibrary insures that the startup and shutdown code that executes when the extension DLL is loaded and unloaded does not corrupt the global MFC state.

So if you are loading a DLL that contains MFC code or if you using threads in your program then you should use it.

That said, at least in modern versions of MFC, AfxLoadLibrary() doesn't do anything special:

```
HINSTANCE AFXAPI AfxLoadLibrary(LPCTSTR lpszModuleName)
{
     ASSERT(lpszModuleName != NULL);
     HINSTANCE hInstLib = LoadLibrary(lpszModuleName);
     return hInstLib;
}
```

So nothing is going to blow up badly if you guess wrong at this.  Thank goodness.

Comment: @nobugz, help me with my terminology.  Is a plain C++ DLL considered an "extension DLL?"  I read that before asking my question, but I was only confused by it.  In one sense, all DLLs are "extensions," but my reading was that MSDN referring more to how MFC uses DLLs.  Am I wrong?

Comment: It is MFC-speak for "DLL containing MFC code".  That's what the state doowop is about, such a DLL has to be wired into the MFC app model.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I thought.

Comment: @HansPassant's answer is spot on. I'll add that this is one of the many little "gotchas" with MFC. Some (like this) are relics, but others aren't. The complexity is enough to wonder how MFC apps manage to work as well as they do.

Answer (score 3):

If you're creating a plain C++ DLL that doesn't make use of MFC at all, you don't need to create an MFC DLL and you should be able to use plain `LoadLibrary()`.